# Python Column values mapping

Tags: python, pandas

I am new to python, I wanted to solve one problem statement, where the i have read the file in dataframe and one of the column looks like as mentioned below.

```
Col1  
ABC#XYZ @1#A0  
ABC#XYZ @1#A0  
ABC#XYZ @1#A0  
ABC#XYZ @1
ABC
```

Just to mentioned, I do other columns like col1 col2 ... in the original dataset.

My problem is, I wanted to get mapping of ABC/XYZ/A0 from our mapping file, which is again i read from csv an another dataframe.

col1 is having 3 different fields in it, those are : field1,field2,field3
and there mapping values are 123,456,789 from csv mapping file.

```
So the current mapping is  
field1: 123 
field2: 456
field3: 789
```

Please help me to achieve my final desire output as :

```
Out_Col1  
123#456#789   
123#456#789   
123#456#789   
123#456
123
```

Note - "#" is the delimiter of the field mentioned. And field2 is having " %2" which can should be ignore while comparison with mapping file final dataframe expected to have only mapped value which is 456.

Comment: What have you tried so far?

Comment: @jpp I have read both the input and mapping file csv and join it on the basic of key.  And for the Col1, I split the column's (Col1) values into different columns. from here I don't know about 2 things: 1) as Col1 has 3 fields in it - Split is working for just field-1 as it is always there but for field-2 and field-3 i was getting error while split. And 2) after successful split how i can map with another dataframe object and place the value into one column again.

Comment: @jpp please let me know if you have any other approach that i can use in this scenario. Thanks in advance.